# C++, "comparison is always true due to limited range of data type"

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm having problem with this for loop:
The compiler says: 
"error: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]"
referring to the "for(...)" part.
I don't understand why, since the comparison isn't always true.

```
for(unsigned char i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(dec % 2 == 0) binary[i] = '0';
    else binary[i] = '1';
    if(dec/2 <= 0) return binary; else dec /= 2;
}
```

Comment: Unsigned values are always >= 0.

Comment: You have an `unsigned char`. It can only hold values between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i` is 0, `i >= 0` will be true, and you'll apply `i--`.

Then, what value do you expect `i` to take ? It cannot take the `-1` value, because it is unsigned, so `i` will become 255.

But 255 is `>=0` so the loop will continue. Forever.

Instead, consider using:

```
for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
```